# Dart Functions as First Class Objects

Tags: function, object, dart

```
 int add(int n1,int n2) {
 return n1+n2;
   }

  1.Function calc1=add;

  2.Function calc2=(int n1,int n2) {
   return n1+n2;
   };


  3.var calc3=(int n1,int n2)=>{
   n1+n2
  };

  4.var callc=(int n1,int n2) {
  return n1+n2;
   };
```

Are all these doing the same thing?

In 1.Function calc1=add , is this pointing to the memory of add function or setting itself to the add function?

In 4. I am getting the error "The type of function literal can't be inferred because the literal has as block as it's body" but if I replace var keyword with Function then no error?Why?

Comment: Cases 1 and 2 declare `calc1` and `calc2` as `Function` with unspecified arguments and an unspecified return type.  You instead should use `var` to allow type inference to assign a more specific type or explicitly use `int Function(int, int)`.  Case 3 returns a `Set<int>`. Regarding question 1, I don't understand what distinction you're trying to make.  Regarding question 4, I cannot reproduce that error.  Please provide the exact code and exact error message (the typos in your version indicate that it is not exact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These do slightly different things that may or may not act the same depending on how you use them.

1.

```dart
Function calc1 = add;
```

Declares a variable of type `Function` and assigns a reference to the `add` function to it.
If `add` is top-level, static or local variable, then all references to it is going to be the same value. If you refer an instance function (a method), you create a new closure every time.

2.

```dart
Function calc2=(int n1,int n2) {
  return n1+n2;
};
```

Declares a variable with type `Function`, then evaluates a function literal to a function value. Each evaluation of that literal creates a new object.

3.

```dart
var calc3=(int n1,int n2)=>{
   n1+n2
};
```

You probably meant to write

```dart
var calc3=(int n1,int n2)=>
   n1+n2;
```

This is almost equivalent to 2. A body of `=> expression;` is a shorthand for `{ return expression; }`. However, you declare the variable as `var`, not `Function`, so type inference gives the variable the type `int Function(int, int)`.

4.

```dart
var callc=(int n1,int n2) {
  return n1+n2;
};
```

Completely equivalent to 3 if you do it as a local variable, but as a top-level variable, type inference does not look into the body to find the return type.

What you see is not an error, just a helpful info. I'm also not entirely sure it's correct. When I check the cpde in DartPad, it actually infers `int Function(int, int)` for `var x = (int x, int y) { return x + y; };`.

The biggest difference between the different cases in practice is that number 1 does not create a new closure each time it's evaluated, and that number 1 and 2 have type `Function` instead of `int Function(int, int)`. That affects type checking, because `Function` allows any call to be made, while the precise function type only allows you to call the function with two integers (and knows that the result is an integer).

Comment: In no.2  "Each evaluation of that literal creates a new object." as you said....Does this mean it creates a function in the memory and that Function calc2 is acting as a reference to that anonymous function that we have created?

Comment: Yes. Each evaluation of the declaration `Function calc2 = (int n1,int n2) {return n1+n2;};` creates a new "anonymous" function object in memory (each evaluation of a function literal does that), then it creates a new variable `calc2` referring to that object. You can change the reference stored in `calc2` later. The compiler might share some code between the different function objects, but it does allocate a new object each time.